# Twitter API integration in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, twitter

I am trying to integrate Twitter account with my application in vb.net. I downloaded the library (.dll file) **TwitterVB2.dll** and got access token from dev.twitter.com. Now I am feeling in trouble while running my app the code is following it gives me an exception after compile and run.

Code:

```
Imports TwitterVB2

Public Class Form1
  Dim twitter As New TwitterVB2.TwitterAPI

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        twitter.authenticatewith("", " ", "", " ")
        PicProfile.BackColor = Color.White
        PicProfile.ImageLocation = twitter.AccountInformation.ProfileImageUrl

        LblHi.Text = "Hi," + twitter.AccountInformation.Name

        For Each tweet As TwitterStatus In twitter.HomeTimeline
              TxtPost.AppendText(vbNewLine + vbNewLine + tweet.User.ScreenName + vbNewLine + tweet.Text + vbNewLine + tweet.CreatedAtLocalTime + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "----------------")
        Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What exception did you get?

Comment: Why is your `authenticatewith` empty. Right now it seems you are not even authenticating to Twitter. Also you forgot to post your exception, which would help...

Comment: I added all four string in authenticatewith too.

Comment: Exception of type 'TwitterAPIException' was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of TwitterVB.

I stopped maintaining this library in 2011. Since then, Twitter has made changes to their API, and TwitterVB no longer works.  If you are so inclined, the source code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/DWRoelands/TwitterVB).  The license is very permissive and I'm sure that a clever developer could get it working with less than a day's effort.